# Reference for the use of moving upper quartile window

Tags: references, quantiles, moving-window, interquartile

I used a moving upper quartile window to select some data, but I require some kind of reference justifying its use and I cannot find anything suitable for it. Does anyone know of a book/paper that talks about a moving upper quartile window?

Comment: Why do *you* use it? What did other people do when they tried to achieve the same thing you are trying to do?

Comment: I used it mainly because I was suggested it through this site :p and I don't know anyone else who has used it for the work that I've performed

Comment: Suggested through this site? Then link to that suggestion, please.

Answer (score 1):

William S. Cleveland and Beat Kleiner. 1975. A Graphical Technique for Enhancing Scatterplots with Moving Statistics. *Technometrics* 17: 447–54. doi:10.2307/1268431 calculated moving upper and lower semi-midmeans. These are the midmeans of the upper and lower halves of the data, above and below a median. The midmean is the mean of the middle half of the data. Thus, these were means of the quantiles for 62.5-87.5% points and for 12.5-37.5% points respectively and thus similar in spirit to moving quartiles, yet based directly on more of the data.